# Switch in Nissan Caravan

Tags: nissan, control

I recently bought a Nissan Caravan (year 2000) and I still don't know the function of two switches. Unfortunately I don't have a manual and I couldn't find information on Google. Maybe someone knows what the switches/knobs shown in the pictures are for? Thanks, Stefan [image][image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The second one looks like for an interior light. The first one, no clue.

Comment: First one is most likely after market. And the second probably fog or interior lights.

Comment: Is this van equipped with a diesel engine? Have you attempted to use the switch? Does anything happen or any lights on the dash illuminate?

Comment: Yes. It's a 3.2l diesel engine. And it's a 4x4. I tried to use the switch but nothing happens. I realized that the internal lights . I'll replace the lamp asap and try again..

Answer (score 1):

The first looks like a valet or kill switch for an after market alarm system. Look for a black box under the dash somewhere or a non oem led indicating alarm.

The second is, based on the logo. For internal lights or fog lights. It could be wired to something else completely and unless it's fairly obvious when you flip it, you would have to trace the wire out. Based on the screw hole right below it, that car was obviously nodded without a delicate touch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Good point. Never thought about subsequent modifications. :)

Answer (score 0):

- The first is **throttle idle control** for diesel. Turning the switch clock wise makes idle faster or vice versa.
- The second one is the **interior light master switch**.